# inconsistency between heroku doc and pg:ingress command

Tags: postgresql, heroku

According to heroku documentation about Heroku Shared Postgresql addon, I can use pg:ingress to know connection string details related to specific database. link below

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-shared-postgresql

```
$ heroku pg:ingress <DATABASE_NAME>
```

but when I run this command, I get:

```
$heroku pg:ingress HEROKU_SHARED_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE
 !    `pg:ingress` is not a heroku command.
 !    See `heroku help` for additional details.
```

Any thoughts on this?

**UPDATED**:

**Platform used**: windows

**Project Type**: django project

**Heroku client version**:

```
$heroku --version
2.24.1
```

**Heroku addons installed**

```
$heroku addons
heroku-shared-postgresql:basic => HEROKU_SHARED_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE
```

Comment: are you using an up to date version of the heroku gem? Their doc caveats - "Previously a plugin was needed to use this addon with the heroku command line client. However, since Heroku client v2.19.0 this plugin is no longer necessary."

Comment: @john-beynon updated my question with some local platform details (being more specific)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new command is `heroku pg:credentials`. I've updated the article, thanks.

Comment: hmm, I get the following error:`pg:credentials` is not a heroku command.